# How to get mail event like read,delete,reply,forward for a mail in outlook in c#

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, add-in

I have to create a addin for outlook using C#. Which will keep track of all mail events like new mail, read, reply,forward and delete etc.

I know how to create add in but I am not getting any idea how I can track event fired by outlook for all these operations.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to research [Application events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.applicationevents_11_event_members%28v=office.12%29.aspx), [Folder Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolderevents_12_event_members%28v=office.12%29.aspx), and [Item Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemsevents_event_members%28v=office.12%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Here is an MSDN example on how to attach to the event which fires when new [messages are received](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268998%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) in Outlook 2007. Events vary by Outlook version, so you need to determine which is the minimum supported version and stick with that eventing API. Some events have special restrictions, but you need to ask more specific questions after you've researched the events.

Comment: SliverNinja : Please i need help about caputring the event for reply & reply To All i have written the code but i am having the problem with detaching the Handler Please look in to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911177/shared-add-ins-for-outlook-2007-capturing-replytoall-event/14914107#comment21061863_14914107