# Shared Add-ins for Outlook 2007 Capturing ReplyToAll Event

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, add-in, outlook-addin

I am using VS 2010 & Dot Net Framework 2.0.
I have created a project in Extensibility->Shared Add-ins for Outlook.
I am trying to capture ReplyToAll Event it is not getting fired.
Please look the below code:

**OnConnection Method**

```
inspectors = applicationObject.Inspectors;                        
inspectors.NewInspector += new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(inspectors_NewInspector);


void inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
    {
        mailItem = null;
        try
        {
            Outlook.NameSpace ns = Inspector.Session;
            Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(
              Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

            foreach (object o in inbox.Items)
            {
                mailItem = o as Outlook.MailItem;
                if (mailItem != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (mailItem == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Couldn't find a mail item.");
            }
            else
            {
                ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).ReplyAll += new
                    Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyAllEventHandler(Connect_ReplyAll);
            }                              
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("asdgh"+ex.StackTrace);
        }        
    }


void Connect_ReplyAll(object Response, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Response+"Hello You have Clikced ReplyTOAll");
    }
```

But the Connect_ReplyAll method is been invoked 
What is Wrong ?

The new Code which is working but the event is registered

```
public void OnConnection(object application, Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref System.Array custom)
    {
        try
        {
             applicationObject = (Outlook.Application)application;
            if (connectMode != Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_Startup)
            {
                OnStartupComplete(ref custom);
            }
            addInInstance = addInInst;
            inspectors = applicationObject.Inspectors;
            explorer = applicationObject.Explorers.Application.ActiveExplorer();

            explorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(explorer_SelectionChange);                                                
            inspectors.NewInspector += new 
                Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(inspectors_NewInspector);               
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(""+ex.StackTrace);
        }
        //((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Reply += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(ReplyToAllEvent);
    }

void explorer_SelectionChange()
    {
        try
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mailExplorer=null;
            mailTO = "";
            mailCC = "";
            mailBCC = "";
            foreach (object selectedItem in explorer.Selection)
            {
                mailExplorer = selectedItem as Outlook.MailItem;
                //MessageBox.Show("" + mailItem.EntryID.ToString());
                break;
            }               
            if (mailExplorer != null)
            {
                if (selectedItems.Contains(mailExplorer.EntryID.ToString()))
                {
                    selectedItems.Remove(mailExplorer.EntryID);
                    ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailExplorer).ReplyAll -= new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyAllEventHandler(Connect_ReplyAll);
                    ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailExplorer).Reply -= new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(Connect_Reply);                        
                }                    
                ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailExplorer).ReplyAll +=
                    new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyAllEventHandler(Connect_ReplyAll);
                ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailExplorer).Reply +=
                    new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_ReplyEventHandler(Connect_Reply);
                selectedItems.Add(mailExplorer.EntryID);
                mailTO = mailExplorer.To;
                mailCC = mailExplorer.CC;
                mailBCC = mailExplorer.BCC;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {                
            MessageBox.Show(""+ex.StackTrace);
        }                                 
    }
```

"Once I register the mailitem with ReplyAll Event If the same mailitem is selected then the event fires multiple times." this issue is resolved by using the above code but i am getting new error when i Detach the Event
Please help me Out

I am getting this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The COM object that you expect to raise the event needs to be alive. Your code above loops through all items in the Inbox (ouch! why?) and uses the same variable on each iteration thus wiping out the previous value.
To reply to a message, it needs to be selected first, thus you only need to loop through the selected items (Explorer.Selection collection). Track the selection by hooking the Explorer.SelectionChanged event, in that event handler, loop through all items in the Explorer.Selection collaction and put them in your own `List<MailItem>` list. This way the objects will be alive until you remove them frm the list.
Better than that, instead of using `List<MailItem>` list, create your own wrapper that stores MailItem as a private member and hook up the ReplyAll event in that wrapper. This way when the event fires, your will know which MailItem object raised the event. The wrappers for each selected MailItem can then be stored in a `List<MyMailItemWrapper>` collection.

Comment: can you just show me example how to capture Outlook Events like ReplyToAll Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I do not have a ready-to-run sample code snippet. What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: I just want to capture REplyToAll event and override this event to check mailitem having more than one recipient or Prompt to show you were BCC for this message etc

Comment: I understand that, but it will be more than just a few lines of code - see my reply.

Comment: I got it will post the answer for all of those who are new Com Add-ins

Comment: I was able to override the Reply To All event but the problem is Explorer.Selection is called every time a we select a mail in the mailbox and it registers the Event for that mailitem this is creating a problem I am updating my Question with new code please help me out.

Comment: Again, there can be more than one selected message. Each of these messages must be stored in a list to make sure it is alive.

Comment: But Reply To All Button gets activated only if one message selected.so assume if i have selected Mail 1 then ReplyToAll event gets register for this mailitem and than i select Mail 2 and once again I select Mail 1. Once Again REplyToAll event gets register for this mailitem and when i click on ReplyToAll command button override method for REplyToAll i.e. connect_ReplyToAll gets called two times.I am not getting how to stop it by getting register twice with same mailitem.

Comment: @Dmirty : "Each of these messages must be stored in a list to make sure it is alive". But how can i make sure that it is alive.

Comment: When selection changes, remove the cached mail items before adding new objects. If the object is referenced (e.g. by being storedi in a list) it is alive and will not be garbage collected.

Comment: Dmitry Streblechenko : Please can you tell me what is the problem in my code I am getting an Error.

Comment: Dmitry Streblechenko :I have never created a Wrapper class please can you show me or given an example to create one.

Comment: @C_J - take a look at the [`InspectorWrapper` and `MailItemWrapper` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff973716%28v=office.14%29.aspx). You cannot use a list of `EntryIDs` - you must use a wrapper or `List<MailItem>` to properly manage the events.